# Hving trouble with VLC

Tags: vlc, 15.04

I recently updated to Ubuntu 15. When trying to open any file with VLC nothing happens, even though it appears to be installed correctly. I believe it has something to do with the fact that that I had installed a pre-release in 14.10. I don't know what to do, please someone help.

Comment: I know I should comment, but I do not have enough reputation points. Please open Terminal (`Ctrl + Alt + T`) and run this command: vlc
Copy the output and paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc && sudo apt-get autoremove --purge && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc
```

1. Purges VLC
2. Purges VLC's dependencies
3. Updates the `apt` cache
4. Reinstalls VLC